# Apache Camel: Keeping routing information completely independent of the Java Code

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix, enterprise-integration

First of all thanks to folks who are currently involved in the development of Camel, I am grateful for all the hard work they have put in.

I am looking for some design advice.

The architecture is something like this:
I have a bunch of Java classes which when instantiated are required to connect to each other and send messages using Apache Camel. The design constraints require me to create a framework such that all routing information, producers, consumers, endpoints etc should be a part of the camel-context.xml.

An individual should have the capability to modify such a file and completely change the existing route without having the Java code available to him.(The Java code would not be provided, only the compiled Jar would be)

For example in One setup, 
**Bean A ->Bean B->Bean C->file->email.**
in another
**Bean B->Bean A->Bean C->ftp->file->email**
We have tried various approached, but if the originating bean is not implemented as a Java DSL, the **messages rate is very high because camel constantly invokes Bean A in the first example and Bean B in the second**(they being the source).

Bean A and Bean B originate messages and are event driven. In case the required event occurs, the beans send out a notification message.

My transformations are very simple and I do not require the power of Java DSL at all. 
To summarize, I have the following questions:

1) Considering the above constraints, I do I ensure all routing information, including destination addresses, everything is a part of the camel context file?

2) Are there example I can look at for keeping the routing information completely independent of the java code?

3) How do I ensure Camel does not constantly invoke the originating bean?

4) Does Camel constantly invoke just the originating bean or any bean it sends & messages to irrespective of the position of the bean in the entire messaging queue?

I have run out of options trying various ways to set this up. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about hiding the middleware on the Camel wiki pages. This allows you to let clients use an interface to send/receive messages but totally unaware of Camel (no Camel API used at all).

Even better consider buying the Camel in Action book and read chapter 14 which talks about this.
http://www.manning.com/ibsen/

Save 41% on Manning books: Camel in Action or ActiveMQ in Action. Use code s2941. Expires 6th oct. http://www.manning.com/ibsen/

Comment: Thanks, got hold of the book. Chapter 14 looks pretty interesting. Will bug you again if I have any more questions.

Comment: I think I should probably give up on the idea of executing this inside Fuse Servicemix. Configuration in chapter 14 only works camel:run. It's not possible to execute it when deploying to servicemix.

Comment: You can still make use of ServiceMix by placing all of the Java code in a bundle and deploying it, while externalising the routing logic in a Spring/Blueprint file and dropping that file by itself in the {smx_home}/etc directory. That file will be started up as a bundle.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider using ServiceMix of FuseESB, you might want to separate your routes in two parts.

First part would be the Event-driver bean that trigger the route. It could push messages to the ServiceNMR (see http://camel.apache.org/nmr.html).

The other part would be left to the framework users, using Spring DSL. It would just listen to message on the NMR (push by the other route) and do whatever they want with it.

Of course endpoint definition could be propertized using servicemix configuration service (see http://camel.apache.org/properties.html#Properties-UsingBlueprintpropertyplaceholderwithCamelroutes)